# AWS naming conventions

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm an experienced programmer but until very recently, I have never worked with AWS. Pretty much every programming language has extensive, fairly standard naming convensions.

What are some best practices on giving names and tagging entities in AWS?

Answer (score 2):

I'm naming entities in companies I work for like so:

awsapplicationelb-productName-AWS_Region-environment-number, for example:

```
awsapplicationelb-renderer-usw1-staging-01
```

Or for an IAM role:

AWS_Service-policy_aim-environment, for exmaple:

```
s3-ReadBucketTest-production
```

Just find whatever convention that suits you and saves you time by including some identifying information in the name.